# An unusual behaviour when using printf() after scanf()

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, buffer-overflow

I am using `scanf()` to get the password from the user and store it in `password` variable which has a size of 20 bytes. I check the entered password against the the `correctPassword` and if they match, boolean variable `pass` will be changed to `true`.

So, when I enter a password which is longer than 20 chars, a buffer overflow happens and the value of `pass` becomes non-zero (ie true). However, when I use `printf()` to print the address of variable `pass` no buffer overflow happens even-though I use a password which is longer than 20 chars.

here is the code that leads to overflow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[20];
    char correctPassword[] = "random";
    bool pass = false;
    
    printf("enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if (strcmp(password, correctPassword) == 0) {
        // compare the two strings,strcmp() returns 0 if two strings values are the same.
        pass = true;
    }
    if (pass) {
        printf("Connecting you to the central system...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Password is wrong! entry denied\n");
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", pass);

    return 0;
}
```

when password entered is in this case 40 chars long(ASCII value of `a` is 97), value of pass changes to 97(true).

```
enter your password: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Connecting you to the central system...
97
```

here is the same code but with one extra line at the end to print the address of variable `pass`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[20];
    char correctPassword[] = "random";
    bool pass = false;
    printf("enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if (strcmp(password, correctPassword) == 0) {
        // compare the two strings,strcmp() returns 0 if two strings values are the same.
        pass = true;
    }
    if (pass) {
        printf("Connecting you to the central system...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Password is wrong! entry denied\n");
    }

    printf("%d\n", pass);
    printf("%x\n", &pass);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case password entered is 40 chars long but `pass` is still `0` (false).

```
enter your password: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Password is wrong! entry denied
0
61fec4
```

So, my question is how could adding only

```
printf("%x\n", &pass);
```

leads to no buffer-overflow as expected?

Comment: Writing out-of-bounds invokes *undefined behavior* and allows *anything* to happen. Use `scanf("%19s", password);` to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: `printf("%x\n", &pass);` also invokes *undefined behavior* because data having wrong type is passed: `%x` expects `unsigned int` while the type of `&pass` is `bool*`.

Comment: You need to simply not write broken code that has undefined behaviour; it is almost never fruitful to analyse why undefined behaviour manifests in a particular way on any given day. (The compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants, but it might _happen_ to do something different if you print.)

Comment: You should have the compiler emit assmebly language code (or disassemble compiled binary) and examine that to search for detailed reason of this findings. The order of variables on memory might be changed or some of them may be stored only on registers.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments

Comment: @MikeCAT Is that something that I can do with a normal compiler?

Comment: @semjz You can use `-S` option in gcc and `/FA` option in Visual C++.

Comment: Consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Comment: @MikeCAT how could I use printf to print a bool* pointer, I could not find a suitable format specifier in the manual. or is there any other function to use? thanks in advance.

Comment: `printf("%x\n", &pass);` -> `printf("%p\n", (void*)&pass);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%s", password)` is a security flaw: any input word longer than 19 bytes will cause `scanf()` to write beyond the end of the array, triggering undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior can have unpredictable side effects, which can be visible or not. The output of `97` is a mild side effect, but a long enough input will corrupt the return address and cause a segmentation fault upon returning from `main()` and a cleverly constructed input might allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code. Changing the program likely changes the side effects as the allocation of the local variables may be different for example when you take the address of `&pass`. None of this is predictable.

Note also that `printf("%x\n", &pass);` has undefined behavior too because `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, not a `bool *`, you should write `printf("%p\n", (void *)&pass);`

There is a simple way to prevent this by passing a length field to `scanf()`:

```
    scanf("%19s", password);
```

Note however that you should also check the return value to detect premature end of file and you should also flush the rest of the input line.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[20];
    char correctPassword[] = "random";
    bool pass = false;
    int c;

    printf("enter your password: ");
    if (scanf("%19s", password) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* read and discard the rest of the line */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;

    if (strcmp(password, correctPassword) == 0) {
        // compare the two strings,strcmp() returns 0 if two strings values are the same.
        pass = true;
    }
    if (pass) {
        printf("Connecting you to the central system...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Password is wrong! entry denied\n");
    }

    printf("%d\n", pass);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, I just have one question.If we don't flush the rest of the input line do we leave a security hole in the program or is it just the matter of cleaning up?sorry for my lack of understanding I just recently started learning C.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate more on this line, why we need to check for EOF and '\n' at the same time?'''      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;'''

Comment: @semjz: flushing the rest of the line is just a matter of cleaning up. `scanf()` will just consume one word, or the first 19 characters if more were typed. A more elaborate program would perform further input after this password check and the pending characters may cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @semjz: the loop checks for both `'\n'` and `EOF` because if the stream reached the end of file without an intervening newline, you would have an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference of EOF and '\n' here why would it be an infinite loop without checking for '\n'.

Comment: @semjz: the purpose of the loop is to consume all bytes until and including the newline. A naive version is `while (getchar() != '\n') continue;` but this would cause an infinite loop if `stdin` reaches the end of file without an intervening newline, for example if the user types `random` followed by **control-D** which on POSIX systems signals the end of file.